# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac x n)^x e^{-x}}{(x-2)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac x n)^x e^{-x}}{(x-2)!}$$

where $x$ is $\mathbb N$-valued and $n$ is some nonzero real number.

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=7c220a2091c26a7f5e9f1cfb099511e3) seems to give $0$ for different values of $n$ that I tried.

Is it really $0$ for any nonzero real $n$? I tried Stolz–Cesàro, but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Do you know [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: It seems undefined as l hospital multiple times gives $\infty/\infty$

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I forgot it. Thanks! ^-^

Comment: @ArchisWelankar How can you use lhospitals? You mean stolz-cesaro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\left(\frac x n\right)^x e^{-x}}{(x-2)!}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^x}{n^xe^x(x-2)!}\tag1\\ 
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^x(x-1)x}{n^x e^x \color{brown}{x!}}\tag2\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^x(x-1)x}{n^x e^x \color{brown}{\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\tfrac xe\right)^x}}\tag3\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\color{#C00}{x^x}(x-1)x\cdot {\color{royalblue}{e^x}}}{n^x \color{royalblue}{e^x} \sqrt{2\pi x}\color{#C00}{x^x}}\tag4\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x-1)x}{n^x\sqrt{2\pi x}}\tag5\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{x^{3/2}-x^{1/2}}{n^x}\tag6\\
&=\begin{cases}\infty,&n\in(0,1]\\ 0,&n\in(1,\infty)\end{cases}.\tag7
\end{align}$$
**Explanation:**
$(2)$ $(x-2)!=\tfrac{x!}{(x-1)x}$.
$(3)$ [Stirling's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html): $x! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x$.
$(7)$ $n^x$ is strictly decreasing for $n\in(0,1)$ and strictly increasing for $n\in(1,\infty)$, in the former case the exponential grows much faster than $x\mapsto x^{3/2}-x^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks workaholic. Can we strengthen the conclusion to include negative n? I guess we might run into problems with even x so no?

Comment: @BCLC You're welcome. If we choose a negative $n$ then that would involve complex numbers, $\left(\tfrac xn\right)^x$ wouldn't even be continuous.