# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) = 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

For a **beginning calculus student**, prove [$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) = 2\pi$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20n%20to%20infinity%204n%5E3%2F(2n%5E2%2B1)%20(pi%2Fn))

---

I'm guessing this means something like

**Allowed**: Pre-university maths, precalculus, basic calculus up to techniques of integration, [Bernoulli's rule](http://math.wonderhowto.com/how-to/find-limits-with-lh-pitals-bernoullis-rule-373323/) for sequences, [two police persons theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) for sequences, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n)$ if $f$ is continuous

**[Not allowed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/inadmissible-theorems-in-research/116035#116035)**: Monotone Convergence Theorem, Taylor series, polar coordinates and advanced stuff in real and complex analysis and the like (eg limsup, liminf, Stolz–Cesàro theorem, Cauchy sequences)

---

What I tried:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \frac{\pi}{n} = 2\pi$$

To use the two police persons theorem, I need to find some $a_n$ s.t.

1. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 2\pi$$
2. $$\frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) \ge a_n $$
3. $$a_n \ne \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$$

Questions:

1. What $a_n$ can I use?
2. How else can I approach this problem?
3. Might I be able to say that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) \color{red}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \frac{\pi}{n} = 2\pi$$

because $\lim \sin(\pi/n) = \lim \pi/n$ and for the same reason that justifies step 3 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1640464/140308)?

So it's like

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \frac{\pi}{n} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\frac{\pi}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \frac{\pi}{n} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\frac{\pi}{n}} = 2\pi (1) = 2\pi$$

?

4. What is the technique here exactly? Usually whenever I see a trigonometric function (eg $\sin$ or $\cos$), my instinct is to ignore the argument and focus on the range if possible (eg $[-1,1]$). However, that would seem to give me $-\infty < L < \infty$

Comment: Presumably you are allowed to use the fact that ${\sin x \over x } \to 1$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes! Hahaha. So the proof in #3 is correct?

Comment: Yes. You could expand the expression (divide above and below by $n^2$ and simplify) to make it even clearer.

Comment: As a simple rule to get a basic idea, I generally just replace a function by the first two Taylor series terms and see if that helps.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah thanks. So the technique/trick/principle/heuristic/whatever is that for trigonometric functions, consider: squeeze theorem, [small-angle approxmation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation)? Anything else?

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. Added Taylor in not allowed :P

Comment: I understand that, but it gives you a hint of what to do. To some extent, using the $\sin x \over x$ rule is using Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @copper.hat How so? $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is the classical example of a limit where Taylor / l'Hopital doesn't really help (unless your $\sin x$ is _defined_ from the Taylor series), so you need something else to calculate it.

Comment: @Arthur: That is how I would define it.

Comment: @copper.hat the $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ limit can be shown using squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \frac{\pi}{n} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\frac{\pi}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^3}{2n^2+1} \frac{\pi}{n} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\frac{\pi}{n}} = 2\pi (1) = 2\pi$$

When one sees $\sin$ or $\cos$, it's not necessarily for squeeze. It could be for applying $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

which I think is extended to something like:

$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)} = 1$$

where $c \in \overline{\mathbb R}$, $f(x) \ne 0$ is continuous and differentiable and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c} f'(x) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

answer to question 3: yes, you definitely can change $\sin { \dfrac { \pi  }{ n }  } $ to $ \dfrac { \pi  }{ n }   $ directly without applying $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { x }  }{ x }  } =1$. that's called substitution of equivalence infinitesimal.

Comment: What are the relationships exactly? Is it that changing $\sin(pi/n)$ to $\pi/n$ is allowed because of that limit fact? Or is it that some third fact (substitution of equivalence infinitesimal?) is the reason behind that limit fact and why we are allowed to change?